# How to Accept Input from the Keyboard using Java?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want this Syntax Except Scanner.I know Scanner Works good for this program.

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print("Enter USN:");
String usn=br.readLine();
```

I want to accept both integer and character type input from the keyboard in a single line.

Comment: Wouldn't the Scanner class work better here?

Comment: I Know this Syntax works good for Scanner .But i want Except Scanner.

Comment: Your current code will read numbers and characters, so I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: My problem is it doesn't take any integer value.

Answer (score 2):

Run this code

```
import java.io.*;  
    class G5{  
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{  

    InputStreamReader r=new InputStreamReader(System.in);  
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(r);  

    System.out.println("Enter your name");  
    String name=br.readLine();  
    System.out.println("Welcome "+name);  
     }  
    }
```